# Why can't I connect to github with my ssh key on yubikey

Tags: github, ssh, git-bash, yubico, yubikey

I have an SSH key generated on my desktop as well as one generated on my yubikey. Both are ED25519 keys, with the one on the yubikey being an ED25519-sk for the security key. When I run "ssh -t git@github.com" to attempt to connect to github to test the ssh key with the desktop key it works just fine and connects successfully. However when I load in the SK from the yubikey and attempt to connect I get permission denied. I have properly added both keys to my github account as well as to the ssh-agent. I've run out of ideas of what could be wrong??

Here are my debug logs:

```
$ ssh -tv git@github.com
OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.113.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-adca5b9e
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-adca5b9e
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/USER/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/USER/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/USER/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key:  ED25519-SK ********************************** authenticator agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key:  ED25519-SK ********************************** authenticator agent
debug1: Server accepts key:  ED25519-SK ********************************** authenticator agent
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ED25519-SK "" from agent: agent refused operation
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "`ssh -t git@github.com`" to attempt to connect to github to test the ssh key with the desktop key it works just fine and connects successfully.

From your log, the test is not successful, since you should see a Welcome message:

```
Hi USERNAME! 
You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Double-check "[Security keys are now supported for SSH Git operations](https://github.blog/2021-05-10-security-keys-supported-ssh-git-operations/)", and if your security key supports FIDO2 resident keys, consider using a [resident key](https://www.yubico.com/blog/github-now-supports-ssh-security-keys/#h-using-resident-keys).

For your test to use your ED25519-sk, try and force it with:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk git@github.com
```

---

Note that you might need [Git for Windows 2.39-rc1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.39.0-rc1.windows.1), which states:

> It is [now possible](https://github.com/git-for-windows/MSYS2-packages/commit/6823ee7b329b53f38747f64db8fb8d6de077a0e4) to generate and use [SSH keys protected by security keys](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#FIDO_AUTHENTICATOR) (AKA FIDO devices) via Windows Hello, e.g. via `ssh-keygen.exe -t ecdsa-sk`.

(Just in case "libfido2 upgraded to v0.12.0" could bring any benefit to your current command)

Comment: Obviously it’s not connecting…that’s why I’m asking the question. Also the link you sent is for using yubikey for account 2factor authorization…not SSH repository key login.

Comment: The debug messages show that your key got accepted by the server.
However, the agent refuses to sign using your key (`agent refused operation`).
I would expect a message `Confirm user presence for key ED25519-SK`.  
How did you generate the ssh key?

Other things to check:

- does it work without adding the key to ssh-agent?
- are the file permissions on your key files correct (mode `600` on `~/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk`)?
- are you running on macOS? In the case: is `ssh-agent` from the same build as your ssh client?

Comment: @joostd Try first generating it without passphrase `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sk -P ""`. That way, the agent should not be needed.

Comment: @joostd the key I generated is already a resident key. I generated it with the following command “ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -O resident -O verify-required -C ‘my email’ “ also I am running on windows 11 and my key is a series 5 so it IS ed25519 compatible.

Comment: @Austin Did you associate a passphrase at the time of its creation?

Comment: Yes I did @VonC

Comment: @Austin I would test another key created without passphrase, to see if it works better (without having to deal with any SSH agent)

Comment: @VonC So i added a key without a passphrase and it only half works. It works if I add the key to the local system by running "ssh-keygen -K" and then renaming both installed files to id_ed25519_sk. However, I would like to temporarily store the key in the agent if on a nonsecure system and not locally install it. That is why I would rather use "keygen-add -K" But for some reason, Github is not reading the key within the agent.

Comment: @Austin No passphrase means no agent. and it means your original `ssh-keygen` command + `-P ""`: `ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -O resident -O verify-required -C ‘my email’ -P ""`

Comment: @austin you van also strip the password from your keyfile using:
    `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk -p -P "password" -N ""`
It is not necessary anyway if you are using the PIN on your YubiKey

Comment: @vonC the thing is I WANT to be able to store the key in the agent every time I plug in my yubikey and use the Fido pin to access it. This way I do not have to generate a fingerprint file on the local system, I’m just adding it directly to the agent. The question is WHY does GitHub not read the key from the ssh-agent using “ssh-add -K”

Comment: @Austin As described in "[Using resident keys](https://www.yubico.com/blog/github-now-supports-ssh-security-keys/#h-using-resident-keys)", This (`ssh-add -K`) will load a “key handle” into the SSH agent and make the key available for use on the new computer. This works great for short visits, but it won’t last forever – you’ll need to run `ssh-add` again if you reboot the computer, for example. To import the key permanently, instead run: `$ ssh-keygen -K`". So did you try `ssh-keygen -K` instead?

Comment: @vonC yes, ssh-keygen -K works just fine for me…however, I want to use ssh-add -K instead for a non secure system…I understand it will be removed after reboot which is what I want. However I cannot figure out why git cannot find my key when added into the agent…am I not explaining myself properly here as I feel I’m asking the same question over and over again…

Comment: @Austin Got it, but I don't know why ssh-add -K does not seem to be supported. Did you test it with the latest Git 2.39.0-rc1, just in case it helps? (link in my edited answer)

Answer (score 1):

You might be hitting this:

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/discussions/2220

You could try fixing it in an elevated command prompt like this:

```
sc qprivs ssh-agent
sc privs ssh-agent SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege/SeTcbPrivilege/SeBackupPrivilege/SeRestorePrivilege/SeImpersonatePrivilege
sc stop ssh-agent
sc start ssh-agent
```

The first command queries the privileges the service currently has, in my case it was empty.